# use grouper to aggregate by week from the exact day

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to aggregate my data on week, using pandas grouper, where the week ends at the exact same day of my last date, and not the end of the week.

This is the code I wrote:

```
fp.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date',freq='w')).collectionName.nunique().tail(10)
```

And these are the results:

```
date
2021-10-03     644
2021-10-10     698
2021-10-17     756
2021-10-24     839
2021-10-31     883
2021-11-07     905
2021-11-14     961
2021-11-21    1028
2021-11-28     990
2021-12-05     726
Freq: W-SUN, Name: collectionName, dtype: int64
```

The last date I have is `2021-12-02`, so I would like that to be the last day of the week aggregate, and it goes back every 7 days, to the end (in this case beginning of the dataset).

I need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.DataFrame.resample` with `rule='1w'`, `on='date'` and `origin='end_day'`

Comment: No, what i mean is, using the same code, but instead of it aggregating it ending with the end of the week, which is 2021-12-05, i want it to end by the last date i have which is 2021-12-02

Comment: ValueError: 'origin' should be equal to 'epoch', 'start', 'start_day' or should be a Timestamp convertible type. Got 'end_day' instead.

Comment: `end_day` was added in `1.3.0` so either update or use `epoch` with `offset` (1970-1-1 was a Thursday so add as many days as you need based on your last row)

Comment: i updated, end day doesnt give error, but i am getting same results as always

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you can find the last date prior to grouping. See references here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases and here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01 01:04:16', periods=250), 'val':range(1,251)})

                   date  val
0   2021-01-01 01:04:16    1
1   2021-01-02 01:04:16    2
2   2021-01-03 01:04:16    3
3   2021-01-04 01:04:16    4
4   2021-01-05 01:04:16    5
..                  ...  ...
245 2021-09-03 01:04:16  246
246 2021-09-04 01:04:16  247
247 2021-09-05 01:04:16  248
248 2021-09-06 01:04:16  249
249 2021-09-07 01:04:16  250

[250 rows x 2 columns]

# locate last date and get day of week in correct format
anchor = df['date'].iat[-1].strftime("%a")

df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date',freq='w-' + anchor)).nunique().tail(5)

# week ends on the same day as the original dataset
            val
date
2021-08-10    7
2021-08-17    7
2021-08-24    7
2021-08-31    7
2021-09-07    7
```